# Connect SQLCipher to Ms Access

Tags: vba, sqlite, ms-access, sqlcipher

I have used SQLite for Access backend database in my several programs. for security reason of data I have to create backend databse with SQLCipher, but I couldn't find any way to connect SQLCipher database to Access. Is there ODBC Driver for SQLCipher or manually way to connect the DB to Access ?

Comment: You have Access frontend connecting to SQLite backend and now want Access connection to SQLCipher? According to documentation "Using SQLCipher, an application uses the standard SQLite API to manipulate tables using SQL." I find nothing about integrating Access with SQLCipher.

Comment: Yes, I want to connect access to SQLCipher, unfortunately SQLite is not safe and everyone can see all data of the database, SQLCipher is encrypted version of SQLite and is safe and protected.